# insert datatable and datagridview data to sql

Tags: vb.net

I need to insert a `DataGridView` column and 2 `DataTable` columns into SQL. The code below inserted the `DataGridView` column row by row in order which is what I want, but the `DataTable` column only inserts the first row and copy it on all rows. any idea on how to fix this?

```
_Command = New SqlCommand("insert_student", _Connection)
_Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
_Connection.Open()
_Command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
_Command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@_m_barrImg", SqlDbType.VarBinary))
_Command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@_CurrentImageName", SqlDbType.NChar))
_Command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@_CurrentImageName1", SqlDbType.NChar))

For x = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    _Command.Parameters("@_name").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("name4").Value
    _Command.Parameters("@_m_barrImg").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("CompanyStatusImage").Value

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.DefaultView.Count - 1

        _Command.Parameters("@_CurrentImageName").Value = dt.Rows(i)("CurrentImageName").ToString
        _Command.Parameters("@_CurrentImageName1").Value = dt.Rows(i)("CurrentImageName1").ToString
    Next

    _Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [master] 
GO 

/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[insert_student] Script Date: 07/04/2013 21:47:36 ******/ 

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

ALTER procedure [dbo].[insert_student] (@_m_barrImg varbinary(max),
                                        @_name nvarchar(max)
as 
    insert into tblimgdata(name4,CompanyStatusImage) 
    values (@_name,@_m_barrImg)
```

Comment: You're looping through the `DataTable` inside your For loop for the `DataGridView` - that means the only values from the `DataTable` you're getting are the last row's values from the table.  What is the relationship between the `DataGridView` and the `DataTable`?  Is it 1 for 1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of rows in the `DataGridView` are equal to the number of rows in the `DataTable` (which is what 1 for 1 would indicate), and that they are in the same order, you can dump your inner loop and simply use the outer loop index to get the data from the corresponding row in the `DataTable`:

```
For x = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    _Command.Parameters("@_name").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("name4").Value
    _Command.Parameters("@_m_barrImg").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("CompanyStatusImage").Value

    _Command.Parameters("@_CurrentImageName").Value = dt.Rows(x)("CurrentImageName").ToString
    _Command.Parameters("@_CurrentImageName1").Value = dt.Rows(x)("CurrentImageName1").ToString

    _Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

The above code will take the name4 and CompanyStatusImage values from row "x" in the `DataGridView` and the "CurrentImageName" and "CurrentImageName1" values from row "x" in the `DataTable`.

Comment: Yes it worked, awesom, thank you so much. just one problem, when insert _@name with store procedure from the dgv, the order of the names get changed, any idea why ? I'm gonna post my store procedure.

Comment: @user1858480 - I'll take a look after you post your stored procedure.

Comment: USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insert_student]    Script Date: 07/04/2013 21:47:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER procedure [dbo].[insert_student] (@_m_barrImg varbinary(max),@_name nvarchar(max)

as 
insert into tblimgdata(name4,CompanyStatusImage) values (@_name,@_m_barrImg)

Comment: Not sure why the order of _name is wrong, but this stored procedure doesn't even use the two parameters from the DataTable...?  Also, why are you using the Master database?  You should be using a database you created for the application.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the datatable columns. now, this is not my main issue right now. your code worked for storing the table into sql, but if make changes to to datagridview, the datatable and run the same code to update the sql table, I got error under _Command.Parameters("@_CurrentImageName").Value = dt.Rows(x)("CurrentImageName").ToString
error "There is no row at position 0". I know I'm not suppose to use insert statement for updating but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user1858480 - I suggest posting that as a new question, along with the error you're getting, so as not to confuse this question for future readers.